# advertising Ad control disappear and Throws Exception in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads, advertisement-server

i am getting exception from Adcontrol as

> "A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.Shared.AdException' occurred in Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.dll".

my ad control is disappear and throw this kind of exception so what should i do for this kind of problem please Tell me if anybody known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is probably thrown because there isn't any ad served.

Your app will only receive ads if they are available. If it is not the case, the control disappears. You get that exception while you are debugging the app, but when deployed and executed in a real device, it doesn't make the app break.

Anyway, just to make sure that this is what causes the exception you can subscribe to the `ErrorOccurred` event of the ad control, and check what happens:

```
private void AdControl_ErrorOccurred(object sender, Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs e)  
{  
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ad Error : ({0}) {1}", e.ErrorCode, e.Error);  
}
```

Comment: Thank u for ur Reply, now i am getting "No ad Available" so how to solve this problem? pls help me.

Comment: It is not your problem. It's just that, the server is not serving any ad. There are not always ads available to be shown, specially outside the United States. Just be patient. Also, play by changing ad categories, maybe the service will be serving ads for other categories.